# Matrix version of Berlekamp Massey algorithm

Tags: coding-theory, sequences-and-series

What are the most obvious generalizations of Berlekamp Massey algorithm [1] to matrix sequences?

> [1] [Massey, J. L.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.80.9932), "Shift-register synthesis and BCH decoding", IEEE Trans. Information Theory IT-15 (1): 122–127

Comment: "displacement rank" should bring up quite a number of interesting papers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find [this](http://repository.lib.ncsu.edu/ir/handle/1840.16/3825) dissertation interesting. The author has collected many references of the Matrix versions of the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm (citing Rissansen, Dickinson, Thome and other papers) and its applications.